# Not getting login response from facebook in windows phone 8 app using facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have followed the tutorial "http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/11/14/sign-into-windows-phone-8-apps-with-facebook-login.aspx"

Login to facebook occurs but I don't get the response from facebook. According to "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone/"

The response should come in the format-`msft-{ProductID}://authorize/?
  access_token={user-access-token}&
  expires_in={expiration-time-of-token}`

Response comes in the format-      `"/Protocol?   encodedLaunchUri=msft-4a3aaf7986aa47b38280ada06 authorize-error_Unknown error_error_code_error_description_An_unknown_error_occurred_while_trying_to_authenticate_
with_Facebook error_reason_An_unknown_error_occurred_state_custom_state_string"`

But I get an error - `Not signed in:(An unknown error occurred-#2003) Unknown error occurred while trying to authenticate with Facebook`

Please help where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial works only with Facebook beta. If you are not using the beta version of facebook then the associate Uri scheme will not work properly and a response will not be received. I have used the same tutorial to integrate Facebook in one of my apps.

Comment: I tried my code after installing Facebook beta app on my device. Still its not working. Its giving the same error..
Please help..